# How to avoid using auth-sources when editing with sudo?

Tags: tramp, gpg, sudo, authinfo, root

When I invoke `crux-sudo-edit`, Emacs hangs forever with the following message:

`Decrypting /home/$USER/.authinfo.gpg...0%`

until I press C-g, then it asks:

`Passphrase for symmetric encryption for /home/$USER/.authinfo.gpg:`

(When finding a file with "/sudo::/path/to/file/", Emacs doesn't hang but still want to decrypt my ~/.authinfo.gpg)

Because I don't save my root password there, I press another "C-g", but annoyingly another window shows up:

```
Error while decrypting with "/usr/bin/gpg2":

gpg: error creating keybox '/home/$USER/.gnupg/pubring.kbx': No such file or directory
gpg: keyblock resource '/home/$USER/.gnupg/pubring.kbx': No such file or directory
gpg: AES.CFB encrypted data
```

And it doesn't disappear even after supplying my root password.

Setting `tramp-completion-use-auth-sources` to `nil` doesn't solve this.

This problem only appears after creating "~/.authinfo.gpg".

Edit: thank to TRAMP's maintainer's suggestion below, I have come to stricter solution that only disables `auth-sources` for local sudos, leaving other remote uses (mostly?) intact:

```lisp
 (connection-local-set-profile-variables
  'remote-without-auth-sources
  '((auth-sources . nil)))

 (connection-local-set-profiles
  '(:application tramp :protocol "sudo"
    :user "root" :machine "localhost")
  'remote-without-auth-sources)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the same question as discussed in https://debbugs.gnu.org/46674
In short: Use Tramp 2.5 from GNU ELPA, and apply in your .emacs

```
(connection-local-set-profile-variables
 'remote-without-auth-sources '((auth-sources . nil)))

(connection-local-set-profiles
 '(:application tramp) 'remote-without-auth-sources)
```

Comment: But TRAMP 2.5.0.2 seems to be broken. I keep getting `void function tramp-register-crypt-file-name-handler`,  had to manually autoload it from `tramp-crypt` to work properly.
The cause as I inspected was `defun tramp-register-crypt-file-name-handler` is wrapped inside a `progn` so it's not properly autoloaded.

Comment: The wrapping with `progn` is intended. Could you please show the problem on the `tramp-devel@gnu.org` mailing list? This is better suited for debugging.